# Wrong url set by Breeze for getting the Metadata from ASP.NET Web API OData Service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, metadata, odata, breeze

I am working on a SPA using Durandal, Breeze and Knockout. The back-end service is provided by ASP.NET Web API OData.

I have configured the Breeze to work with OData like this:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
```

and have set the remote service name in Breeze to `'odata'`.

The thing is that the uri that Breeze calls to get the metadata is `odata/$metadata` whereas the uri that seems to work properly (have tested in Fiddler) is `odata?$metadata`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have a special character in your route?  Why not just make the uri odata/metadata?

Answer (score 0):

For Web API OData you should use:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "webApiOData" });
```

just odata is used for wcf odata.